# Make Parallel Jobs Performance

Tags: linux, performance, unix, makefile

I was using `time` to profile `make` builds, and I noticed that having `-j 8` was several milliseconds slower than `-j 4`. I am compiling with gcc on a Intel Core2 Quad, so there are only four processor cores. Could this slowdown be due to the resource limitations, and whatever `make` uses to schedule jobs is adding some overhead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more processes running than processors, then the operating system will require some [context switching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch). This isn't an issue with `make`; it's just how jobs are scheduled when there are insufficient resources.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I would consider a difference of several *milli*-seconds to probably just be statistical noise. Run the tests several times and see if the difference is repeatable before assuming it's significant.

That said, running 8 CPU-bound processes on 4 CPUs will usually run into more multitasking overhead than running two sets of 4 processes. If the make process involves a lot of I/O (and it usually does), there is some benefit to running more than 4 (say 5 or 6) to fill in the CPU queue when other processes are stalled on I/O, but 8 might be overkill.